# How to play video file By using Servlets,Jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am new to java applications development.

I involved in one University website development.In this I have to play the video file which is describes about that university.

Please help me to go forward.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can

1. Embedded flash video player in the webpage. [This article](http://www.instantshift.com/2010/05/14/21-free-video-players-for-your-website-and-blogs/) listed some free available flash player. This technique is commonly used for today's Internet, because of its less browser compatibility problem.
2. Or you can use `video` tag in **HTML5** already built in many modern browsers(such as Chrome, Firefox and IE9+), which however may not be applicable to old browsers that does not support `video` tag in HTML5.

So it is up to you to pick the appropriate approach.